# Filter out small areas

Tags: google-earth-engine

I can't filter out small areas (e.g. 200 sq.m) from the segmented NDVI map.[image]

Is it possible to do that with the GEE means?
The script is here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users/sharovgennady/FieldData:Zones

Comment: I don’t know how it works in google earth engine or with NDVI but in Qgis with a discrete raster l would use a majority filter.